# Cylindrical Shell Volumes Problem

Tags: calculus

Use the method of cylindrical shells to find the volume generated by rotating the region bounded by $y=3+2x−x^2$ and $x+y=3$ about the y-axis.

I have already turned $x+y=3$ into $y=3-x$. However I don't know what to do with the polynomial to continue into graphing them and using the cylindrical shell method $dV=2pirht$. I don't understand how to continue this problem. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$3+2x-x^2=(3-x)(1+x)$, so $y=3+2x-x^2$ is a parabola opening down with $x$-intercepts at $-1$ and $3$; meets the line $x+y=3$ at the points $\langle 0,3\rangle$ and $\langle 3,0\rangle$. The region between the two curves therefore lies in the first quadrant, above the straight line and below the parabola. When you slice it into vertical strips, you get a strip at each $x$ in the interval $[0,3]$.

If $0\le x\le 3$, the top end of the strip at $x$ lies on the parabola, so it has $y$-coordinate $3+2x-x^2$. The bottom end of the strip lies on the straight line, so it has $y$-coordinate $3-x$. The length of the strip, and therefore the height of the cylindrical shell that it generates, is

$$\text{top}-\text{bottom}=(3+2x-x^2)-(3-x)=3x-x^2\;.$$

The radius of the shell is the distance from $x$ to the axis of revolution, which in this problem is the $y$-axis; that distance is $|x-0|=x$, since $x\ge 0$. The thickness of the shell is $dx$, so its volume is

$$dV=2\pi x(3x-x^2)\,dx\;.$$

Can you finish it from there?

Comment: should the next step be 2pi[(3x^(2)-x^(3))] from 0 to 3? Because I did that and ended with just 2pi but it was wrong.

Comment: @JXXII: Yes, $$V=2\pi\int_0^3\left(3x^2-x^3\right)\,dx\;,$$ but that integral isn’t $2\pi$. What did you get for the antiderivative?

Comment: M. Scot Ah, no wonder. I had forgotten the antiderivative. Final answer is (27/2)pi.

Comment: @JXXII: Yes, that looks good.

Comment: @JXXII: You’re welcome!

Comment: I hope this isn't too much to ask but if I ever get another question can I ask you? I liked how without giving me the answer you were the only one who reminded me about the mistake I had done and feel like you can help me get through any future problems I may encounter.

Comment: @BrianMScott ...

Comment: @JXXII: I spend a lot of time here, so if you do ask another question, I’m quite likely to see it. If you want to make it almost certain, you can also leave a comment here addressed to me, with a link to the new question, and I’ll take a look the next time I’m on-line.

Comment: Sounds great, thank you so much again!

Comment: I have another question about cylindrical shells. It reads as follows:


Use the method of cylindrical shells to find the volume generated by rotating the region bounded by $y=x^2$ y=0 and x=1 about the y-axis.


I did the following steps but apparently they are not correct so if you can please point me out in my mistake?


V=2pixf(x)dx
 =2pi(1-x)x^2dx
 =2pi(x^2-x^3)dx
2pi Integral from 0 to 1 (x^2-x^3)dx
 =2pi[(x^3/3)-(x^4/4)] from 0 to 1
 =2pi(1/3-1/4) --> 2pi(4/12-3/12)
 =2pi(1/12) --> (2/12)pi
My Answer=(1/6)pi.
Please Advice.

@BrianMScott

Comment: @JXXII: When you revolve the strip at $x$ about the $y$-axis, the radius of the shell is $x$, not $1-x$. The integral that you set up calculates the volume obtained when you revolve the same region about the line $x=1$: the distance from an $x\in[0,1]$ to that axis **is** $1-x$.

Comment: Awesome. Got it. Thanks @BrianMScott!

Comment: @JXXII: You’re welcome! (And yes, $\pi/2$ is right.)

Answer (score 1):

Draw a picture.

Algebra shows the two curves meet at $x=0$ and $x=3$. One of the curves is a downward opening parabola that reaches its peak at $x=1$. From $x=0$ to $x=3$ the parabola is above the line $x+y=3$.

Now take a vertical slice of width "$dx$" at $x$. This is at distance $x$ from the $y$-axis. The slice has height $(3+2x-x^2)-(3-x)$. It follows that the volume is
$$\int_{x=0}^3 2\pi x\left((3+2x-x^2)-(3-x)\right)\,dx.$$